# Updating The .Text of the TrayNotifyIcon

Tags: c#

I'm currently using the .Text of the TrayNotifyIcon to display a statusdisplay when the user has the mouse over it (for a percentual completion of a process)

Thus I just set: TrayNotifyIcon.Text to the appropriate % of completion.
Example (the following code is part of a code I use where I create a new thread which sets in the subprocess variable if it is completed or not and also how many % completion are. The code below shall display as the TrayNotifyIcon.Text how many % of the subprocess are completed with updates every second):

```
while (subprocess.NotCompleted)
{    
     TrayNotifyIcon.Text = "TextToUpdateTo....." + subprocess.percent.ToString() + "% completion";  
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Now I've seen that it only updates the display whenever I move the mouse and does not update it as soon as I set .Text appropriately.

Thus my quesiton is is there any way to make it so that I can tell the system to update the text that is being displayed?

Comment: Might help if you showed some code

Comment: The "Problem" is that it is not much code only TrayNotifyIcon.Text = "TextToUpdateTo";  will put that in though but like I said to set or update the displayed thext not really much code to be used.

Comment: Tooltips don't have a "dynamic update" feature, that's very counter to what they were designed to do.  You can dynamically update the balloon text.  This is not great UI, changing the icon to simulate a progress bar is reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system displays the hint text when the mouse is hovered over the notification icon. This text is not expected to be dynamic. The display of the text is handled by the system. When it wants to display the hint, it queries the icon for the text, and then displays it. It will not go back and check if the text has been changed, and there is no mechanism to inform the system that the text has been changed and should be updated. This is a feature of the shell (`Shell_NotifyIcon`) rather than anything in the .net libraries.

So, using `TrayNotifyIcon` in its vanilla form, there is nothing you can do to change this behaviour. If you really want dynamic update of hint text you will have to suppress the system drawn hint (by setting `Text` to an empty string) and drawing your own hint window. You'd need to detect the mouse hovering over the icon, and also detect when it leaves the icon.

Frankly, I don't think that this is really a very good piece of UX design. If I were you I would find a different way to let the user receive this feedback.

Comment: The customer I'm creating that info for wanted a small process hint over the trayicon like dropbox for example does it (although I think they also dont update that only when the mouse is moved it gets updated).  Else I wouldn't have gotten the idea to do a dynamic update there. 

Tnx for the explanation there (feared it already that its not possible but wasn't sure there).

Comment: Another app that behaves like this is Process Monitor. Dynamic information but again hint must be closed and reopened to be updated.